# IE 10 and Firefox issues with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, firefox, phpmyadmin

I have built a web form using php and javascript that works great in chrome. However when viewing from IE or Firefox. All data is displayed properly on the final page, however nothing is actually submitted into my database(MySQL/phpmyadmin). These submissions work properly on chrome. When tested against a later version of apache with the lateset version of phpmyadmin and mysql no problems. How do I work around apach2.2 and mysql 5.5.42 in order to solve this...

```
<?php
$premC;
$NoR;
$CC;
$SD;
$HD;
$pack1;
$pack2;
$pack3;
$equipC;
$roomC;
$totalC;
$fname;
$lname;
$emailV;
$_SESSION['rebate'] = $_POST['rebate'];
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','*****','*****','*****');
  if(!$connect){
        die('Could not Connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
    }
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO form_test (Number_of_Rooms,Current_Monthly_Cost,SD,HD,Family,Entertainment,Ultimate,Premium_Features,Equip_Cost,Room_Cost,Total,First_Name,Last_Name,Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss",$NoR,$CC,$SD,$HD,$pack1,$pack2,$pack3,$premC,$equipC,$roomC,$totalC,$fname,$lname,$emailV);
if(isset($_POST['number_rooms'])){ $NoR = $_POST['number_rooms'];$_SESSION['nRooms'] = $NoR; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['current_cost'])){ $CC = $_POST['current_cost']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['sd'])){ $SD = $_POST['sd']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['hd'])){ $HD = $_POST['hd']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['family'])){ $pack1 = $_POST['family']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['entertainment'])){ $pack2 = $_POST['entertainment']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['ultimate'])){ $pack3 = $_POST['ultimate']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['premium'])){ $premC = $_POST['premium']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['equipCost'])){ $equipC = $_POST['equipCost'];$_SESSION['pEquip'] = $equipC; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['roomCost'])){ $roomC = $_POST['roomCost'];$_SESSION['pRoom'] = $roomC;$stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_POST['total'])){ $totalC = $_POST['total'];$_SESSION['pTotal'] = $totalC;$stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_SESSION['fname'])){$fname = $_SESSION['fname']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_SESSION['lname'])){$lname = $_SESSION['lname']; $stmt->execute();}
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){$emailV = $_SESSION['email']; $stmt->execute();}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

If you all need anymore information let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function pageRedirect(){
        window.location="fForm.php";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, this is not a browser issue unless you're using JavaScript somewhere.

Comment: I am using a small redirect  after sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after a weekend of banging my head against a wall I have found my problem. The problem felt so very simple.

```
$POST()
```

vs

```
$_POST()
```

A very small typo was causing my

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){$emailV = $_SESSION['email']; $stmt->execute();}
```

to return false and not excute the statement. A very small silly mistake on my part. I guess the next question is why does Chrome correct for this and not IE?